# adding picture in IDLE using tkinter (and grids)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a project where I create a "virtual" world cup coming up in a few weeks and I want to add the flags. I downloaded a picture of the first country and tried to put it in, but for some reason, it didn't work.
This is a picture of the downloaded picture:

[image]

I had first downloaded a .png file and then converted it to .gif because some tutorials had said so. I had also tried to only use the .png file but that also didn't work. 
This is what I've got right now:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
import tkinter.ttk

#group A
groupA = "group A"
Russia = "Russia"
Saudi_arabia = "Saudi Arabia"
Egypt = "Egypt"
Uruguay = "Uruguay"

#grid stuff
#title
Label(master, text="world cup 2018", font=("Courier", 50)).grid(column =0, row=0, columnspan=15)
#groups
Label(master, text=groupA, font=("Courier", 25)).grid(column =0, row=1, columnspan=3)

#stuff for group A
Label(master, text=Russia, font=("Courier", 10)).grid(column =1, row=4)
Label(master, text=Saudi_arabia, font=("Courier", 10)).grid(column =1, row=6)
Label(master, text=Egypt, font=("Courier", 10)).grid(column =1, row=7)
Label(master, text=Uruguay, font=("Courier", 10)).grid(column =1, row=8)

tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=5, sticky='we')
tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=2, row=2, rowspan=7, sticky='ns')
tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=4, row=2, rowspan=7, sticky='ns')


Label(master, text="teams", font=("Courier", 15)).grid(column =0, row=2, columnspan=3)
Label(master, text="ga/gf", font=("Courier", 10)).grid(column =3, row=2)

Russian_flag = PhotoImage(file="Russian_flag.gif")
Label(master, image=Russian_flag).grid(column=0, row=4)
```

The picture is supposed to go on the left side of the Label Russia

this is what it said when I tried it:
couldn't open

> "Russian_flag.gif": no such file or directory

thank you for your help.
PS. this is done on IDLE on a Raspberry pi

Comment: Your files need to be in the same folder as your python script

Comment: Can you give us the location of the pictures relative to the scripts in your filesystem?

Comment: yes, that works! thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cricket_007 said in comments, the image needs to be in the same directory as the python file.

This is the same for every way* of loading any file into a python program that I can think of, since otherwise how does the program know where to look?

---

<sup>* other than imports from lib</sup>